# Typewriter effect on MathJax not working correctly

Tags: javascript, html, mathjax

I have MathJax and typewriter effect. But the typewriter is showing the Latex code and then after fully displaying the Latex code, it renders it correctly.

In other words, there is a short period where the $ signs and raw LaTeX syntax are visible before being processed by MathJax.

How can I see the actual equation rendered with typewriter display (not the $ and {} showing)

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>MathJax with Typewriter Effect</title>
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
    MathJax.Hub.Config({tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['$', '$'], ['\\(','\\)']]}});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.5/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_SVG"> 
</script>
<style>
    .typewriter {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p id="mathExpression" class="typewriter"></p>

<script>
   const expression = `Write $ \\sqrt[2 ]{2} . \\sqrt[4 ]{5}$ as a rational exponent `;
    let i = 0;
    const speed = 15; /* The speed/duration of the effect in milliseconds */

    function typeWriter() {
        if (i < expression.length) {
            document.getElementById("mathExpression").innerHTML += expression.charAt(i);
            i++;
            setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
        } else {
            MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub, "mathExpression"]);
        }
    }
    typeWriter();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```